# Two ob_start(); to export to separate files

Tags: php

My client's server doesn't support php and requires alot of updates so I had the page export a .html. Now he wants to export part of this page so he can upload it somewhere else.

How do i call two ob_start();, i know its possible but how do i distinquish between the two?

Sample page sudo code

```
ob_start();  //1 obstart  

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
ob_start();   //2 obstart  
<div class="special"></div>
//stop copying obstart #2
</body>
</html>


$contentString =  ob_get_contents();
$divString =  ob_get_contents();

file_put_contents( 'HTMLFile.html', $contentString ); 
file_put_contents( 'specialDIV.txt', $divString );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
ob_start();  //1 obstart  
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$contentString =  ob_get_contents();
ob_start();   //2 obstart 
?> 
<div class="special"></div>
//stop copying obstart #2
</body>
</html>

<?php
$divString =  ob_get_contents();

file_put_contents( 'HTMLFile.html', $contentString ); 
file_put_contents( 'specialDIV.txt', $divString ); 
?>
```

Comment: What i ended up doing is dividing the page into 3 parts

$pagePart1 =  ob_get_contents();
ob_flush();


$pagePart2 =  ob_get_contents();
ob_flush();


$pagePart3 =  ob_get_contents();
ob_flush();

Then i did file put contents combining all three parts
And another just file put content on part2 for the center part

wondering if there is a smarter way